# Swift 2 Use of unresolved Identifier

Tags: swift2

Thanks for taking the time to help me with my query. 
I am receiving a "Use of unresolved identifier" error on my project - this is following a tutorial so shouldn't be happening but I must be doing something wrong. 
Here's the code:

```
 if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.reve­alViewController().panGestureRecognizer(­))
    }
```

The error is specific to the last line which starts "self.view"

Any help is greatly appreciated. Swift 2.0 using xCode v7.2

Thanks
Mat

Comment: Post the error, possibly link the tutorial.

Comment: I'm sure the tutorial does not suggest to use new instances of `revealViewController` all the time.

Comment: You indicated that the error is on the last line, but you didn't indicate which identifier it was complaining about.

Comment: you need to configure bridging header properly to include objective c module

Comment: I thought I had. :)


    //
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

Answer (score 0):

I try to copy the source code on the web follows:
[http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/](https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/)

Errors "Use of unresolved identifier" on disappeared.

Correct code

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:" self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureReconizer())
}
```

---

Error code:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.reve­alViewController().panGestureRecognizer(­))
}
```

---

It is the same, I do not understand why :D

Answer (score -1):

add the following line in NewsTableViewController.swift

```
    import SWRevealViewController
```

also use the #selector as below

```
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
```